# Restrict email access on weekend

Tags: ios, email, iphone-app

I have my work email on my iPhone.  I have a terrible habit of checking it on the weekend just because it is so easy to do and I would like to ween myself off this.

> Is there any software available to restrict email access on the
>   weekend?  Even something that required me to type in a password would
>   do.

Answer (score 1):

If This Then That, ([IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/)), can set up recipes for controlling your email according to time, day of week, location, etc. so you should be able to construct a recipe to disable or lock your email application at weekends unless you are in the office.